# To stratify outcomes in R

Tags: r

I conducted the following analyses on an imputed dataset:

```
fastfood<-with(imp_paper3,
glmer(Fastfood_R~Trans1+Work1+TV1+Comp1+Leisure1
+Country_source+Type_of_neighbourhood
+age+Education+gender+BMI+SURVEY_total_mv
+(1|NBH_NR),family=binomial))

summary(fastfood)
pool(fastfood)
summary(pool(fastfood))
```

However, I would like to repeat the analyses, but stratified by country (i.e. Country_source). Is there someone who knows how to adapt my command?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: could `describeBy` in `psych` package help you? It's very much like `summary` so I think this should go pretty safe `describeBy(fastfood, group=Country_source)`